# Avoid browsing cache in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i want to avoid browsing cache while viewing a document. Please help me solve this issue by using java script or by any other method.

Regards,

Arun

Comment: @Tim B Jamesjust                                                      i need to avoid browser cache while viewing a documents.?

Comment: The 2 responses below would probably do it.  But I would question why you'd want to do it?  Removing cache will seriously effect the performance of your site, I would only remove if your sure it is absolutely necessary to do.

Answer (score 3):

Set `content-expiration` header in your response.

```
    var cache = HttpContext.Curent.Response.Cache;
    cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: This headers does not work for me in Safari 15

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked "in JavaScript" I'll add that you need to use a different URL each time you view the document in JavaScript.  E.g.

`<a href="/a-document" onclick="this.href += '?' + new Date()">`

(this is far from robust, it just illustrates the basic principle of the technique)

You'd only really do it this way if you were unable to control the server (e.g. if you aren't the owner).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following header to your response:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```